# load three xib in UITableView on clicking three different button

Tags: ios, swift

There are three button in a `UIView` and a `UITableView` below the `UIView` i want to load xib on click on button. if first button is click load new xib if second button is click load approved xib if third button is click load rejected xib

[image]

@IBOutlet weak var newButton: UIButton!

```
@IBOutlet weak var approvedButton: UIButton!

@IBOutlet weak var rejectedButton: UIButton!

@IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!

@IBOutlet weak var approvedDownLabel: UILabel!



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    approvedDownLabel.isHidden = true
    rejectedDownLbl.isHidden = true
    addNewTblview.dataSource = self
    addNewTblview.delegate = self
    newButton.isSelected = true
    self.addNewTblview.register(UINib(nibName: "AddInstructorNewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "AddInstructorNewCell")
    self.addNewTblview.register(UINib(nibName: "ApprovedCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "ApprovedCell")
    self.addNewTblview.register(UINib(nibName: "RejectedCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "RejectedCell")
       }
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
      return 4
       }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if newButton.isSelected {
        let cell = self.addNewTblview.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "AddInstructorNewCell", for: indexPath) as! AddInstructorNewCell
        return cell

    } else if approvedButton.isSelected {
        let cell = self.addNewTblview.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ApprovedCell", for: indexPath) as! ApprovedCell
        return cell
    } else {
         let cell = self.addNewTblview.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "RejectedCell", for: indexPath) as! RejectedCell
        return cell
            }
  //    return UITableViewCell()
          }
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if newButton.isSelected {
        return 170
    } else if approvedButton.isSelected{
        return 165
    }else {
        return 178
    }
   // return 170
        }
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableView.automaticDimension
}

}
```

Comment: Add the code you've tried so far.

Comment: You can set condition in cellForRowAtIndexPath() method with which button is tapped by that you can view respective xib

Comment: i am struggling on it

Comment: nothing happen on click on button

Comment: Use container with 3 different viewControllers that is best approach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you create tree cell class with .xib.

```
@IBAction func btnNewClick(_ sender:UIButton)
{
  self.approvedButton.isSelected = false
  self.rejectedButton.isSelected = false
  self.Yourtbl.reloadData()
}
```

set action btnapprovedClick button

```
@IBAction func btnapprovedClick(_ sender:UIButton)
{
       self.approvedButton.isSelected = true
       self.rejectedButton.isSelected = false
       self.newButton.isSelected = false
       self.Yourtbl.reloadData()
}
```

set action btnrejectedClick button

```
@IBAction func btnrejectedClick(_ sender:UIButton)
{
       self.approvedButton.isSelected = false
       self.rejectedButton.isSelected = true
       self.newButton.isSelected = false
       self.Yourtbl.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: I just update my code @DynamoPRo Your code is correct just set condition on your button IBAction  this

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use enum? See the code below for further reference.

```
import UIKit

    enum ViewType {
        case new, approved, rejected
    }

    class ViewController {
        private var viewType: ViewType = .new

        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            switch viewType {
            case .new :
                let cell = self.addNewTblview.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "AddInstructorNewCell", for: indexPath) as! AddInstructorNewCell
                return cell
            case .approved:
                let cell = self.addNewTblview.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ApprovedCell", for: indexPath) as! ApprovedCell
                return cell
            case .rejected:
                let cell = self.addNewTblview.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "RejectedCell", for: indexPath) as! RejectedCell
                return cell
            }
        }

        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
            switch viewType {
            case .new:
                return 170
            case .approved:
                return 165
            case .rejected:
                return 178
            }
        }

        @IBAction func btnNewClick(_ sender:UIButton)
        {
            viewType = .new
            tableView.reloadData()
        }

        @IBAction func btnapprovedClick(_ sender:UIButton)
        {
            viewType = .approved
            tableView.reloadData()
        }

        @IBAction func btnrejectedClick(_ sender:UIButton)
        {
            viewType = .rejected
            tableView.reloadData()
        }

    }
```